# Commands fail - cannot load ntsdexts

Tags: windbg

I'm new to using WinDbg and am running into a problem.  I've set the server for symbols and downloaded them, but I keep getting stuck when I try to run `!htrace` (or any other command actually). The error message I get is

> Cannot load 'ntsdexts'

I get this on any command that starts with an exclamation point (i.e. `!drivers`, `!heap`, `!htrace`, etc.) which is making tracking down a handle leak a problem.

I'm using the `srv*...*` link direct to Microsoft for symbols.

The last line before I get the breakpoint is:

> Module Load:  C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\VFRCORE.DLL  (no symbols loaded)

Comment: copy paste  the actual error sequence  from windbg window

Comment: Looking at my WinDbg directory, `ntsdexts.dll` is located in the `winxp` subfolder of WinDbg. Does it exist on your machine? Which version of WinDbg are you using?

Comment: @blabb Not sure how this will help, but here goes (the darn software here won't take the post - too long, so I pastebin'd it):      http://pastebin.com/jwHuxzn6

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't seem to have this file anywhere on my system.  Not sure where it's supposed to come from.  This is on a Windows 7 machine.  Help | About says 6.1 not sure how to get more detailed than that.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Found a copy of ntdsexts.dll online and put it in the winxp direction as you indicated.  Still getting the same error log from the patebin.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Somehow I managed to get two different version of windbg installed and the one in the path is the wrong one. Put the dll file into the right place, ran from that specific directory and now it works.